# can't connect postgres on the server to postico on my local

Tags: ruby, postgresql, psql

when I connect postgres on the server to postico on my local I get this error

```
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "http://159.65.65.203/" (92.242.140.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I could not find anywhere postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files, so i created the files, as you see in the below image

[image]

I found this explanation but still does not solve my issue

```
Ubuntu does not use the standard pg_ctl for postgreSQL. Instead, it 
uses pg_ctlcluster.
That in turn controls the different PostgreSQL clusters. When you do 
an install of a new cluster, pg_ctlcluster is smart enough to put
postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf into separate dirs.
So to be specific, /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf is just a tmp 
file that you can ingnore, /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf is 
the original version for the 9.4 cluster and
/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.auto.conf is the actual, live
version of the 9.4 cluster that you need to change to affect the 9.4
cluster. Likewise for the pg_hba.conf.
reference https://www.postgresql.org/message- 
id/CANu8FiygR5CdeqRTiE0YM+BQk6aK+qZyw2frH_FWV27J1exong@mail.gmail.com
```

here how i configured postgresql.conf

```
port=5432
listen_addresses='*'
```

here how i configured pg_hba.conf

```
 host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
 host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

when i run

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program 
name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
29761/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Clearly 5432 is not open for all connections.
when i make an api call using postman seems to work.
I use mac currently firewall not on, i have my server on digitalocean use Ubuntu 16.04.6 (LTS) x64.

This is the path of postgres files

```
postgres@borroupapi:~/9.5/main$
```

when i run  find / -name postgresql.conf i get this

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```

but i cant find the path as logged in postgres user

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If this is a new installation keep in mind Postgres 9.5 is pretty much ancient history. Can't you use a newer version? 12.3 is the shipping release.

Comment: @tadman do u think the upgrade will solve the issue. Is this a good link to follow for upgrade https://gist.github.com/Prototype-X/c484f9054b9c185dc76e295fb97690a0

Comment: You always have to back-up when upgrading Postgres, but you should be backing up **as a matter of routine**. Once upgraded you should be able to restore using the correct `pg_restore` binary that matches the server version. Before you upgrade, be absolutely certain the process works by testing on another machine or VM.

Comment: For DBA advice this really should be on [the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to fix the issue in postgres 9.5 postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files are located in

```
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

not in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

you have to login as server root user and run each one of the command and that will give where are the files

```
find / -name postgresql.conf

find / -name pg_hba.conf
```

in my instance when i ran the command i got this

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```